# Let $(Pf)(x) = \frac{f(x) + f(-x)}{2}$. What is the image of $P$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Found this question in "Introduction to Linear Algebra" by Serge Lang. It says

> Let $(Pf)(x) = \frac{f(x) + f(-x)}{2}$. What is the image of $P$?

This is part (d) of the question. Part (b) had me prove that $P$ is a linear map and part (c) had me find its kernel, which I successfully found to be the set of all odd functions. Now, given this information, I contend that the image of the map is the set of all even functions. To prove it I must show that every image is an even function, and that every even function has a preimage:

$$ (Pf)(x) = \frac{f(x) + f(-x)}{2} $$
$$ (Pf)(-x) = \frac{f(-x) + f(x)}{2}$$

Thus $(Pf)(x) = (Pf)(-x)$ and it means it's even.

Now to prove that every even function has a pre-image, let $g(x)$ be an even function and let's try to find its preimage

$$\frac{f(x) + f(-x)}{2} = g(x) \implies f(x) + f(-x) = 2g(x)$$

I should solve for $f(x)$ here but I'm at an impasse. I don't know what else I could do to simplify the function to get rid of $f(-x)$ or how I could use the information that $g(x)$ is even to solve it. Any hints?

Comment: how about $f=g$?

Comment: The image is the even functions, the kernel the odd functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't stated what space $f$ belongs to.  Assuming $f$ is in the space of "functions", then the image of $P$ is the space of even functions.  Certainly, every even function has a pre-image, that function itself!

Comment: It was so obvious, I couldn't see it. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome.